# Import Authentication in POST API Call

Tags: post, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to make a POST API call to an address, including existing cookies, however the request still returns a 403 forbidden error due to authentication requirements.

The request url is as follows.

```
https://www.imdb.com/list/ls093916945/tt0096697/add
```

I'm using existing cookies stored within my browser (after manually logging in to IMDb) and copied across for simplicity of testing.

The current python code is as follows

```
import requests

cookieData = {

    'session-id':'146....',
    'ubid-main':'132.....',
    'adblk':'adblk_yes',
    'x-main':'i2qE6E@EK.....',
    'at-main':'Atza|IwEB.....',
    'sess-at-main':'"ksn3tObY6.....',
    'id':'BCYkx.....',
    'uu':'BCYvWpz6s5.....',
    'sid':'BCYss.....',
    'session-id-time':'20827....',
    'session-token':'5SB4.....',
    'csm-hit':'tb:9A.....1'

}

r = requests.post('https://www.imdb.com/list/ls093916945/tt2724064/add', cookies=cookieData)

print(r)
```

How do I import the cookie authentication data and authenticate my request?

Comment: Add `headers` in your `post` request.

Comment: @MrugeshKadia I've added all the header data (not just cookies_, however I'm still receiving the 403 error.

Comment: @MrugeshKadia No worries. Data formatting issue in request. Works now, many thanks!